# Strange subscribe behaviour

Tags: angular, observable, angularfire2, angular7

I'm working with Angular 6 and I've got a strange subscribe behavior, so when I call reload method for three times from the constructor it works fine and I got three log message "subscribe".

But when I click on a button which have `(click)="reload()"`, the reload is executed but the subscribe is never executed.

`company-edit.component.ts`:

```
export class CompanyEditComponent implements OnInit {
company$ : Observable<any>;
company: Company;
formCompany: Company;
refDb: any;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private companyService: CompanyService) {
    this.refDb = db.object('company');
    this.company$ = this.companyService.getCompanyObservable();
    this.reload();
    this.reload();
    this.reload();
  }

  reload(){
    console.log("reload");
    this.refDb = this.db.object('company');
    this.company$ = this.companyService.getCompanyObservable();
    this.formCompany = new Company("","");
    this.company$.subscribe( (company)=>{ console.log("subscribe");
    
      this.company = company;
      console.log(this.company);
      
      if (company)
        this.formCompany = company;
    });
    // this.formCompany = {"name":"kk","fondator":"gg"};
  }
```

`company-edit.component.html`:

```
<div>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [(ngModel)]="formCompany.name" placeholder="Name">
        </mat-form-field>
        <br>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [(ngModel)]="formCompany.fondator"  placeholder="Fondateur">
        </mat-form-field>
        <br>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary"(click)="submit()">Save</button> |
        <button mat-raised-button color="accent"(click)="update()">Update</button> |
        <button mat-raised-button color="warn"(click)="delete()">Delete</button> |
        <button mat-raised-button color="" (click)="reload()">Reload</button>
    </div>
```

`company.service.ts`:

```
export class CompanyService {
  company$ : Observable<any>;
  refDb: any;

    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
      this.refDb = db.object('company');
      this.company$ = this.refDb.valueChanges();
    }

    getCompanyObservable(){
      return this.company$;
    }
```

Comment: Just a side note, but if you have these buttons inside a form you should specify the button type, otherwise they will per default be submit buttons instead of type="button". I don't know if events are fired in your case.

Comment: Yes I should mention the type of the button inside a form, but for this exemple when I click the button "reload", the function reload() is correctly called but on the execution the sucscribe is ignored.

Comment: Why would you resubscribe to `company$` in the first place? It kind of defeats the purpose. My guess is the reason you're seeing the 3 logs on load, is because the subscriptions are in place before the `Observable` emits data. If nothing's changed, it will not emit data, which would be the reason you're not seeing a 'subscribe' log.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need the latest value received from the server. You can achieve the same by using `BehaviorSubject`

```
export class CompanyService {
  //company$ : Observable<any>;

   public data: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

   refDb: any;

    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
      this.refDb = db.object('company');
      //this.company$ = this.refDb.valueChanges();
      this.refDb.valueChanges().subscribe(data=>this.data.next(data));
    }

    getCompanyObservable(){
      return this.data.asObservable();
    }
```